# Mysqld.sock doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-10.04

I have a MySQL server running on Amazon EC2 in a VPC instance.  I had to change the instance type of it to handle load and when I brought it back up, the socket didn't exist anymore.  The file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock doesn't exist and nor does the directory.

I have no idea where it went, but it is just gone.  So is there a way to fix that? If so how?  The server is running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Confirm that mysqld.sock doesn't exist

```
sudo find / -type s | grep mysqld.sock
```

Check that your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file agrees that the file should be /var/run/mysqld

```
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

and if it does then

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld/
sudo service mysql restart
```

but I suspect your problem lies elsewhere as the mysql start script will create the directory if it doesn't exist. Is there any relevant message in your  mysql logs ?

Comment: Well that seemed to fix everything.  I think the problem was that I was using mysqld and /etc/init.d/mysql start to start the server, but I never tried the service method.  That was the only one that would create the directory and socket.

Comment: bizarrely, i get this every time i enter my server. and every time i must apply this solution to fix it. would be great if there were some permanent fix.

Comment: I got an error like "error: Found option without preceding group in config file: /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line: 24
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted"

Comment: Thanks ..i have same problem , i edited /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and added socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock , mysql server working started after restrat .

Comment: find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied